# PHP & jquery - issue with cache settings for php files request via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, caching

I'm a bit stuck with caching of php files which I request via javascript every xx seconds to reload automatically.

**My Situation**

I have one normal PHP file (lets call it index.php) with a cache-control header like

```
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=60");
```

and then normal content. Now I have a content block which I request via jquery to be refreshed automatically every 60 seconds. This content block is another PHP file which we call "content_block.php" for now.

This .php file have also a cache-control header set which is every 30 seconds.

**Problem**

As you will notice now this 30sec header will be in middle of the  content and thus I get a warning about "Cannot modify header information..." etc.
So the reason for this error is clear for me.
My problem is that .php files are by default set to 3600 minutes on my server, so once I remove the 30sec cache-control header line, the jquery will request the cached file for 3600 minutes max.

So my question is if I can somehow set individual cache-control header in a .php file which gets requested via jquery by another php file which have already a cache-control header set?
Its maybe a simple solution to it, but somehow I couldnt find anything useful to this question, so any ideas and advices are welcome ;)

Comment: Your theory about getting _Cannot modify header information..._ warning is absurd. How exactly does the 30sec header _get in the middle_ and cause the error?

Comment: ensure your `header()` is at the top of your `content_block.php` as the first thing. Ensure no white spaces outside of the `<?php ?>` tags too

Comment: @SalmanA Because he's trying to modify the header information after a previous file modified the header and then wrote to the output stream.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy what output stream? The middle portion is fetched via jQuery so we have two independent files, each with its own headers.